# Java path object Vs File

Tags: file, path, java-7

I am trying to find a read that differentiates the advantages of using a Path object over the File object in java. I see a comparison of the API here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html but don't really see the real advantages anywhere. Any pointer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally one could say that both classes have different focus.
`File` is designed for file handling (creating, deleting, ...) while `Path` is focused on filename parsing.

`File` seems to have most functionality of `Path` included but there may be special cases where `Path` suits better.

Please see the documentation sites (especially methods overview) [java.nio.File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) and [java.nio.file.Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) for further information.